# How do I register a custom bundle with zipline?

Tags: python, csv, quantitative-finance, zipline

I am following the tutorial here:

http://www.prokopyshen.com/create-custom-zipline-data-bundle

and trying to set up a custom bundle to get price from custom, non US financial assets. I am stuck on the line that says:

```
Advise zipline of our bundle by registering it via .zipline/extension.py
```

My extension.py file is located in the .zipline/ directiory and has the following code:

```
from zipline.data.bundles import register
from zipline.data.bundles.viacsv import viacsv
eqSym = {
    "CBA"
}

register(
    'CBA.csv',    # name this whatever you like
    viacsv(eqSym),
)
```

I don't get what it means to register the bundle via .zipline/extension.py though? I thought it might mean to just run the extension.py file from my terminal via a:

```
python extenion.py
```

but that fails and says:

```
ImportError: No module named viacsv
```

How do i register this bundle?

Answer (score 1):

I also followed this tutorial and I must confess this part is a little confusing.

First of all, I don't think it's necessary to run:

```
$ python extension.py
```

The error message you get probably comes from the fact that Python cannot find the `viacsv.py` file in `sys.path` (the places where it looks for modules, etc.). In the tutorial you mentioned, it's not really clear what to do with this file. As far as I am concerned, I just saved the `viacsv.py` file in my local `site-packages` directory. As I am on Linux I put it there `~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` but it might different for you. You can run the following python script to find out:

```py
    import sys

    for dr in sys.path:
        print dr
```

Then I just substituted `from zipline.data.bundles.viacsv import viacsv` with `from viacsv import viacsv` in `extension.py`.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you might be looking for the wrong place for the extension.py file.

For windows machine, the file is under "~\.zipline\extension.py". In my case, it's under "C:\Users\XXXX\.zipline\extension.py".

I had been looking at zipline folder under conda's site-packages folder, and couldn't find it. Then created an extension.py myself wondering why it's not called.

Check a related post here https://www.quantopian.com/posts/zipline-issue-while-creating-custom-bundle-to-bring-yahoo-data.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here, @Gillu13 pointed me to this solution.
I installed zipline through conda. So zipline is installed in 
home/me/anaconda3/envs/krakenex/lib/python3.6/site-packages

in there you will find zipline/data/bundles and you can put viacsv.py in there...

then

```
from zipline.data.bundles.viacsv import viacsv
```

works